# PHP, using array_push or?

Tags: php, arrays

can anyone help me with a little problem, I have array with 1 value in it, and with every submit input I want to add +1 value to array, for example in array I have value [0] -> "Name1", when I press submit button I want to add another value so array would be  [0] -> "Name1", [1] -> "Name2" and when I press again it adds Name3 and so on, I used array_push, but it only adds one value, and then just updates that one value, so, do you have any ideas how to make my code work properly? Thanks!

```
$users = array("Name1");
$_SESSION["add"] = $users;

if(isset($_GET["create"])) {
    $name = $_GET["name"];  

    array_push($_SESSION["add"], $name);

}

foreach($users as $acc) {
    echo $acc;
}
```

Comment: First of all you have to post your code to help you make it work properly

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiline form, which will represent every value from array.

```
echo '<input type="text" name="create[]" value="">';
foreach($_GET['create'] as $name)
{
    echo '<input type="text" name="create[]" value="$name">';
}
```

So you can iterate over each field in array, show it to user and let him edit entries and add new. You can access names as array in php ($_GET['names'], $_POST['names']);

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array in which you store your data in a session/cookies/database. When your script stops executing, this array doesn't exist anymore, so when you submit a form, the new array is created.

Comment: I tried using sessions but when I use it, it only shows first value which is created by adding it directly to array, I will add code to my question,

Comment: Have you called a ```session_start()``` anywhere before the code you had posted?

Answer (score 0):

Check here how its working i think it working as par you said : 
  http://www.tutorialsscripts.com/php-tutorials/array-functions/php-array_push-function-demo.php

Comment: Yes, I want exactly as given here, but where can I find that code example?

Comment: The code in the link is: 
$arrays = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
  array_push($arrays,'six','sevena');
  print_r($arrays);
It's just an example, I thought it will be whole code, like in the page